# Problem when send a xmlHTTP request

Tags: java, request, character, xmlhttprequest

When I send a string with text = "Frédéric" via a xmlHttp request to my server side code then I get in my Action for the String the following text = "Fr?d?ric".
This is for all the special characters like ü, è, é,...

Strange issue, because when I test this on my DEV machine then this works fine and I get the text Frédéric. When I test this on my UAT/PROD machine then I get the text "Fr?d?ric" in the string.

The JDK is the same version 1.5.0_17 on DEV and UAT/PROD.

I have really no idea at this moment... :-(

Please help me!

Thanks,
progrs

Comment: Character encoding in UTF-8 will work. No?

Comment: At my XmlHttpRequest I also set the header with the charset UTF-8.
But the result is the same...
XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")

Answer (score 0):

I used Base64 encoding to solve problems of charsets in AJAX. Encode string before sending and decode it in recepient.